# base change of adele rings

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, adeles

I read Neukirch’s book “Algebraic Number Theory”, and its remark following to proposition VI.2.3, there is an assertion that natural map $\mathbb{A}_K \otimes_K L \to \mathbb{A}_L$ is isomorphism. How can it be proved ?

Comment: Can you say what you have done so far? For example, can you think of a *candidate* mapping from the tensor product to the adele ring of the larger field? Are you familiar with the isomorphism from $K_v \otimes_K L$ to $\prod_{w\mid v} L_w$ for each place $v$ of $K$?

Comment: I have an agreement to the fact that for each place $v$ there is the isomorphism $K_v \otimes_K L \to \prod_{w|v} L_w$, however the difficulty is still existing (in my thought). The map is described by the usage of restricted products. Does tensor product commute to restricted product?

Comment: Do you see how $\mathbb A_K \otimes_K L$ and $\mathbb A_L$ are both $\mathbb A_K$-modules, and that both of these are free $\mathbb A_K$-modules of (finite) rank $[L:K]$?  If that is too general, think first about a concrete example like $K = \mathbf Q$ and $L = \mathbf Q(i)$.  The point is that to prove a ring homomorphism $A \to B$ is an isomorphism where $A$ and $B$ are not just rings but also $R$-modules for a ring $R$, think linearly and try to show the mapping is an $R$-module isomorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Theorem 1 in Chapter IV-1 of Weil: Basic Number Theory. See also Corollaries 1-2 after the proof of this theorem.